# What is the difference between final TextEditingController _controller=TextEditingController() and final _controller=TextEditingController()?

Tags: flutter

I saw  both these  `final TextEditingController _controller=TextEditingController()` and `final  _controller=TextEditingController()` in some developers code.What is the difference between both these declarations and which one is the better way?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are specifying the type of the variable (i.e. TextEditingController) explicitly.

In the second one _controller variable will be assigned the TextEditingController by [type inference](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#type-inference).

The first one makes the code more readable and less prone to errors (i.e. compile time errors revealed before).